# mmap.PROT_EXEC windows equivalent in mmap python

Tags: python, windows, mmap

I'm looking for the equivalent of the linux "mmap.PROT_EXEC" method for windows. (Inside mmap module on python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going down to raw `ctypes` access to the underlying APIs (`CreateFileMapping`/`MapViewOfFile`), this can't be done. The `access` arguments (used on Windows, and mapped to equivalent `flags`/`prot` flags on Linux) defined by Python are strictly limited to `ACCESS_READ`, `ACCESS_WRITE`, `ACCESS_COPY` and `ACCESS_DEFAULT`, and none of them allow the memory to be mapped executable.

Comment: I'm sure a patch would be welcome. The mmap module predates the addition of the `FILE_MAP_EXECUTE` and `PAGE_EXECUTE_*` constants in Windows XP SP2. Python 3.5 dropped support for XP, so this capability can easily be added to 3.8 or 3.9.